# How reliable is Symfonys2 EmailValidator checkMX?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, mx-record

Like in title, how reliable is this check.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/EmailValidator.php#L139-L142

Every single server in the world have their MX record exposed to the world?
Or is there a possibility that there exists a server that hides their MX record and even if email will be valid, check will fail.

**UPDATE**:

I have already checked Symfony documentation and source.
I know and I've tested that only emails domain is checked, not the user part.
I just don't know how reliable it is. Is it always possible to check servers MX records.

Comment: mx checking for email validation is considered a bad idea.

Comment: @Dagon Could you expand? Some servers don't have MX records and are using MTA and A record for email exchange. Is that the reason or is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validator only check if the DNS user in the email is valid for example if you set this email `fail@google.com` it will be validated even this email doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html#checkmx

The `checkMX` option is done using PHP's [checkdnsrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) function, along with the `checkHost` option.  You can also set a `strict` option and include the [egulias/email-validator](https://packagist.org/packages/egulias/email-validator) library for tighter restrictions.  Using those options should be completely sufficient and reliable in determining if an email address is valid.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, It seems like a good idea in theory and in practice will work most of the time but there will be occasions where the MX lookup fails due to network issues etc, and then the email will return as invalid, this then causes users who have inserted their correct email to become frustrated.

This in turn then causes developers to have to spend time looking at what went wrong.

Additionally, if a user is putting in a fake email, all they need do is use a real domain and fake user (like fbjdsbafjkbsdjafj @gmail.com) so it is of limited usefulness.

For 99.9% of cases it will be sufficient to check for email well-formedness without mx lookup using an established email checking library, (rather that roll-your-own)